# Format the result of loop php

Tags: php

I'm stuck of this making a table with 4 columns, and the data of the table comes from an array, this is code I've done:

```
$sample // this is an array and it has 15 values inside
<table>
foreach($sample as $x){
$rows="<td>$x</td>".$rows;
$l++;
if($l==4){
echo"<tr>".$rows."</tr>";
$l=0;
$rows="";
}
}
</table>
```

If I'm correct this code will produce a table width 3 rows and 4 columns, the missing content is that I need to include all of the data inside the $sample I need this kind of output for this code.

```
[1][1][1][1]
[1][1][1][1]
[1][1][1][1]
[1][1][1][0]
```

the 1 are the array value of $sample while the zero has no value, because the value og $ sample is 15 only

Comment: Please do everybody (including yourself) a huge favor and start indenting your code. Also I'm pretty sure the above code will either result in a syntax error or PHP code being outputted.

Comment: 3 * 4 != 15... and apart from that, *very* wrong approach to everything.

Comment: I believe this is correct: [**LINK**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bd9-ftp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    $sample = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15");          #with 15 rows
    echo "<tr>";
    $key   = 1; 
    foreach($sample as $each){
        if( ($key%4) == 0){
            echo "<td>{$each}</td></tr><tr>";
        }else{
            echo "<td>{$each}</td>";
        }
        $key++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `tr`s will be closed correctly?

Comment: Yes, the code is tested on my localhost, why is it downvoted? @PeeHaa

Comment: My comment should be a hint...